# Push Notification integration steps in android

Tags: android

I am new in android apps development. Can anybody suggest me how to use push notification in android application. It will be helpful for me if you give step by step integration steps.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: Stack Overflow is not here to do your research for you. Not only is this not about a specific programming problem (and therefore off-topic), but you could have easily [punched this into Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=android+push+notification).

Comment: try this link  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: It is nice to have such helpful people in this world. Given links are really helpful for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the `step by step instructions` as well as the `source code` from [**this tutorial**](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

It includes very good `graphical representations for better understanding`.

I hope it will be helpful.

[image: Push Notification Diagram]

Comment: Thanks Good Explanation. its helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

there are various players who will helps u for push notification one of them is parse. it is very simple to integrate push notification in android. Also u can look through GCM (Google cloud messaging)

https://www.parse.com/

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html