# How to send device to device push notification in android through firebase

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new to android firebase and notifications.
I have created my basic android application in which user(s) of type say x sends a request to user of type y.
The request gets generated fine and user of type y can click on the pending request button to see the list of request from user x but i want to inform the user type y through push notification when x generates a request.

Any tutorial or detailed explanation with code would be really helpful as I could not find anything useful til now

Comment: Asking for tutorials or other off-site resources is off topic on Stack Overflow. But you could do worse than this post on the Firebase blog: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html

Answer (score 1):

You can not generate notification from mobile, Notification is fared from Backed, 
It is possible when you want to generate push notification then first call webservice of database and database fired notification to particular phone device

[how to integrate pushnotification in android](https://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-android)

[step wise description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19995619/4997704)

Comment: I have implemented my backend through php/mysql.can you provide any source/link which this can be useful for me?

Comment: see above Both link